# Not able to run MKS integrity query

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

Getting below error while executing MKS integrity query.

Cannot show view information: Your query was stopped because it was using too may system resources.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is likely taking longer than the time alotted by the Integrity server to queries.  By default this value is 15 seconds.  This usually indicates that your query is very broad or that an index needs to be created in the database to help increase the performance of the query.  The latter requires the assistance of your database administrator.

DISCLAIMER: I am employed by the PTC Integrity Business Unit (formerly MKS).

Answer (score 0):

one thing that you can check is if your query could have a very big list of items as results. try adding more restrictive filters first and then ease them step by step. At least this was my use case :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use filter as much as can, when you use filters it’s limiting unnecessary results.

Comment: The order of answers changes depending on which one are Active, Oldest and Votes. So please don't use "Agree with above comment", as we don't know which one you mean.